# JQuery click function not getting called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple page for testing with only a button, I am linking to an external js file. It is displaying the jquery version in a alert box, but when the button is clicked nothing happens. What is wrong  with this?

Here is my simple test html page

```
<title>Insert title here</title>
<!-- scripts -->
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input  type="button"  tabindex="5"  value="jscript" id="testbutton" />
</form>
</body>
```

and here is my myscript file content

```
alert($.fn.jquery);
$('#testbutton').click(function(){
alert("test successful");
});
```

I am using JQuery version 1.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably because the DOM is not [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) for JavaScript processing at the time of bindiing the click handler. Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#testbutton').click(function(){
        alert("test successful");
    });
});
```

Comment: @Abhishek - Just to point out, I did answer first, but okay. (order the answers by oldest first) :)

Comment: sorry i did not see the time. Thanks again!

Comment: 44 seconds makes all the difference! (+1 for both though) :)

Answer (score 2):

You need a document.ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert($.fn.jquery);
  $('#testbutton').click(function(){
    alert("test successful");
  });
});
```

That's because your `#testbutton` can't be referenced until it's loaded

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Thanks it worked. so this .ready() function is required at least once i suppose?

Comment: Sorry Edgar, I did not see before but Karim79 answered my question 1st :)